# How to Auto rebuild my module to new Kernel?

Tags: drivers, updates, kernel

New to linux, after doing this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2092934

I got my wifi up and running, ignorantly, i clicked to update my computer and it came with a new kernel, but it killed my wifi.

Doing it over again is not a problem, but i would like it done automatically in future, DKMS or something? And also, where/how do i delete old kernels once i'm not using them anymore?.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [tim_phillips](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=464774) in the [same post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2092934&p=12621449#post12621449) he offered an .deb package that will install the DKMS modules:

> The vendor drivers for the RealTek 8188cus chip, in the Edimax
>   EW-7811Un for example, do not compile on ubuntu 13.04, kernels 3.8 or
>   3.9.
>
> There are errors with implicit declarations of functions (daemonize),
>   and unknown symbols in modules.
>
> RTL8188CUS
>
> the deb contains patched versions of the driver source code from
>   RTL8192xC_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105.zip available at
>   [Realtek site](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=274&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#2742) which on its own doesn't compile on ubuntu
>   13.04 kernel 3.8 or 3.9
>
> this deb package will compile, install the 8192cu.ko driver, and
>   insert a DKMS module so that it is done on each kernel upgrade.
>
> don't forget to blacklist the native drivers: put a file in to
>   /etc/modprobe.d/ with this in it
>
> ```
> # Blacklist native RealTek 8188CUs drivers
> blacklist rtl8192cu
> blacklist rtl8192c_common
> blacklist rtlwifi
> ```

([source](https://code.google.com/p/realtek-8188cus-wireless-drivers-3444749-ubuntu-1304/))

You can download the package [here](https://code.google.com/p/realtek-8188cus-wireless-drivers-3444749-ubuntu-1304/downloads/detail?name=rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms_1.6_all.deb&can=2&q=) and install it:

```
wget "https://code.google.com/p/realtek-8188cus-wireless-drivers-3444749-ubuntu-1304/downloads/detail?name=rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms_1.6_all.deb&can=2&q="
sudo dpkg -i rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms_1.6_all.deb
```